# Just upgraded to Xcode 6.2 - bundle identifier nearly impossible to enter

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode-6.2

I just upgraded to Xcode v6.2, and the bundle identifier field is nearly impossible to use. After each character I type, it loses focus.

Am I doing something totally stupid, or is this a bug in Xcode?

UPDATE: This issue also affects the Build and version fields.

Also, after changing the values in info.plist, it still does not work properly for me on the General tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems a bug in xcode 6.1 and 6.2.Once you change Bundle identifier in info.plist , Then its editable in general tab next time .
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set it in info.plist first, it was bugging for me too, but after that it somehow got fixed.

Comment: Good workaround... Did the behavior of the main Bundle Identifier field later change so that it works, or do you just use Info.plist now?

Comment: another issue that let me wonder if the developers of XCode actually use XCode :)